# link href not working on links returned using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a live search suggestion box. my data with link's hrefs are returning successfully by an ajax call, but when I click on the links, it doesn't take me to the linked URL. But if I right-click and do open link in a new tab it's working perfectly. Everything is working fine except for the link.

HTML-

```
<div class="dropdown">
                    <div class="input-group" >
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="employee_search" id="employee_search" placeholder="Employee name">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-search"></i> Search</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg" id="search_result" style="width:100%!important;"></div>
                </div>
```

PHP Ajax -

```
public function ajax_employee_search(Request $request){
        $search_value = request('search_value');
        if(strlen($search_value) > 1){
            $users = User::where('name','LIKE','%'.$search_value.'%')->where('is_active', '!=', 2)->take(5)->get();
            foreach($users as $user){
                $employee_name = $user->name;
                echo '<a href="'.url('employees/profile', $user->id).'" class="dropdown-item search-result-item">'.$employee_name.'</a>';              
            }
        }
    }
```

Javascript -

```
 $('#employee_search').on('keyup',function(){
                $('#search_result').dropdown('hide');           
                $('#search_result').html('');
                var search_value = $(this).val();
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                });

                 $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'/ajax-employee-search',
                    data:{ search_value: search_value },
                    success:function(result){
                        if(result.length > 0){      
                            $('#search_result').dropdown('show');            
                            $('#search_result').html(result);            
                        } else{
                            $('#search_result').dropdown('hide');                   
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: What is `dropdown`? Does it work without Ajax if the links are just hardcoded in there? Did you inspect the HTML and verify the links coming back from the server are valid?

Comment: I'm actually using the bootstrap dropdown style to show the search suggestions. And yes, data with links are coming from server.

Comment: @DebarshiDas Can you show some returned result?

Comment: Even if I give a static link like google.com in the ajax code, it doesn't work when I click on the link. But works perfectly if I right-click on the link and do open in a new tab or window.